# How can I connect Mac OSX MIDI with node.js?

Tags: node.js, midi

I tried [this](https://github.com/justinlatimer/node-midi), but no dice. I want to be able to receive MIDI messages in a node.js server, nothing more, nothing less. Does anyone have an easy(ish) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need this https://github.com/thomasjachmann/portmidi
or look at his example https://github.com/hanshuebner/midivent

Answer (score 1):

https://npmjs.org/package/midi works quite well. I made a MIDI to OSC bridge with node that I pushed here: http://github.com/pwhelan/node-midiosc-bridge.